# How to set action for calls not answered?

Tags: twilio, twilio-studio

I'm using Twilio Studio for a simple phone system.

I would like an Incoming Call to ring 3 phone numbers simultanueously (I figure out how to do that w/ the connect_call_1), but how do I pick an action if no one picks up?  I would like it to connect to a voicemail if no one picks up

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Twilio Studio Split Based on Widget to determine the result of the DialCallStatus (using the respective Studio Variable) and make a widget routing decision based on the returned valued.

[Dial Call Status](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/dial#dialcallstatus)